# Phase shifting image content after analyzing with riesz transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, motion, multiscaleimage

I am working on a project involving video motion magnification algorithms. Currently I am trying to understand phase based motion magnification using a riesz pyramid. My main source of information is this document:

[Riesz Pyramids for Fast Phase-Based Video Magnification](http://people.csail.mit.edu/nwadhwa/riesz-pyramid/RieszPyr.pdf)
\

I have performed the following steps to attempt to reproduce some of the results in the paper:

1. Decompose an image into multiple scales using the provided matlab code for the riesz pyramid
2. Generate the images Riesz1 and Riesz2 by convolving one subband of the pyramid with [-0.5, 0, 0.5] and [-0.5, 0, 0.5]' using the approximate riesz transform introduced in the paper.
3. Determine the dominant local orientation in every pixel of the subband by calculating atan(R2/R1). This calculation is derived from equation 3 in the paper.
4. Steer the transform to the dominant local orientation and calculate the resulting quadrature pair
5. Use the quadrature pair to generate a complex number (I + iQ) whose phase I then used to determine the local phase in the specific pixel.

This is the Matlab code I created:

```
%Generate a circle image
img = zeros(512, 512);
img(:) = 128;
rad = 180;
for i = size(img, 1)/2 - rad : size(img,1)/2 + rad
    for j = size(img, 2)/2 - rad : size(img,2)/2 + rad
        deltaX = abs(size(img, 1)/2 - i);
        deltaY = abs(size(img, 2)/2 - j);
        if (sqrt(deltaX^2+deltaY^2) <= rad)
           img(i, j) = 255;
        end
    end
end

%build riesz pyramid
[pyr, pind] = buildNewPyr(img);

%extract band2 from pyramid (no orientation information yet)
I = pyrBand(pyr,pind,3);

%convolve band2 with approximate riesz filter for first quadrature pair
%element
R1 = conv2(I, [0.5, 0, -0.5], 'same');

%convolve band2 with approximate riesz filter (rotated by 90°) for second
%quadrature pair element
R2 = conv2(I, [0.5, 0, -0.5]', 'same');

% show the resulting image containing orientation information!
% imshow(band2_r2, []);

%To extract the phase, we have to steer the pyramid to its dominant local
%orientation. Orientation is calculated as atan(R2/R1)
theta = atan(R2./R1);
theta(isnan(theta) | isinf(theta)) = 0;
%imshow(theta, []);

% create quadrature pair
Q = zeros(size(theta, 1), size(theta, 2));

for i = 1:size(theta, 1)
    for j = 1:size(theta, 1)
        if theta(i, j) ~= 0
            %create rotation matrix
            rot_mat = ...
                [cos(theta(i, j)), sin(theta(i, j));...
                -sin(theta(i, j)) cos(theta(i, j))];

            %steer to dominant local orientation(theta) and set Q
            resultPair = rot_mat*[R1(i, j), R2(i,j)]';
            Q(i,j) = resultPair(1);
        end 
    end
end

% create amplitude and phase image
A = abs(complex(I, Q));
Phi = angle(complex(I, Q));
```

The generated images look like this:

[image: Generated Images]

Now my questions:

1. When calculating theta using atan(R2/R1) I get a lot of artifacts in the result (see image "dominant orientation"). Is there something obvious I miss here/do wrong?
2. Assuming what my results are correct thus far. To magnify motion I need to not only be able to determine the local phase, but also to change it. I seem to miss something obvious, but how would I go about that? Do I need to somehow change the phase of the pyramid subband pixels and then collapse the pyramid? If yes, how?

I am (obviously) quite new to this topic and only have a rudimentary understanding of image processing. I would be very thankful for any answer, be it a solution to my problems or just a referral to an other useful source of information.

Sincerely

Comment: Hi! Did you continue the work within this field? Any basic advice (and some interesting resources - source code/papers) for someone trying to start understanding and working this field? Thanks!

Comment: @Matei_Radu Do you mean signal signal/video processing in general or motion magnification? For the latter, there are several interesting resources. Here's a paper disussing a Lagrangian approach, based on optical flow algorithms: http://people.csail.mit.edu/billf/publications/Motion_Magnification.pdf
Here you got a more recent Eulerian approach using intensity variations, for which there is a working MATLAB demonstration available:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/papers/vidmag.pdf

Comment: I'm talking about motion magnification, yes. I will read the paper you sent me and get back to you. Thanks for this. Any resources you can think of that treat this subject are welcomed! Best of luck!

Comment: I added some information. Also, based on the first Eulerian approach I mentioned, there is a paper discussing a Eulerian approach using complex phase variations:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/nwadhwa/phase-video/phase-video.pdf
And based on that, that we have the Riesz motion magnification I mentioned in the original question. I did indeed finish the implementation of the algorithm in my software. It's a really, really interesting topic! Also, I would recommend you start with the first paper discussing the Eulerian approach. It's the least complicated and the provided MATLAB code is helpful.

Comment: Did you manage to render video with video magnification using the Riesz Pyramid?

Comment: I had a working implementation, however, there were major artifacts I couldn't eliminate in time. Therefore I went for an alternative using a complex steerable pyramid (second Eulerian approach I linked), which works remarkably well and is capable of real-time motion magnification even on low end hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a functioning implementation of this algorithm. Here are the steps I took to successfully motion-magnify a video using this method.

These steps should be applied to each channel of a video sequence that you (I have tried it for RGB video, you could probably get away with doing it for just luminance, in a YUV video).

1. Create an image pyramid of each frame. The original paper has a recommended pyramid structure to allow greater magnification values, although it works fairly well with a Laplacian pyramid.
2. For each pyramid level of each video channel, calculate the Riesz transform (see [The Riesz transform and simultaneous representations of phase, energy and orientation in spatial vision](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698910002750) for an overview of the transform, and see the paper in the original question for an efficient approximate implementation).
3. Using the Riesz transform, calculate the local amplitude, orientation and phase for each pixel of each pyramid level of each video frame. The following Matlab code will calculate the local orientation, phase and amplitude of a (double format) image using the approximate Riesz transform:

   ```
   function [orientation, phase, amplitude] = riesz(image)

   [imHeight, imWidth] = size(image);

   %approx riesz, from Riesz Pyramids for Fast Phase-Based Video Magnification

   dxkernel = zeros(size(image));
   dxkernel(1, 2)=-0.5;
   dxkernel(1,imWidth) = 0.5;


   dykernel = zeros(size(image));
   dykernel(2, 1) = -0.5;
   dykernel(imHeight, 1) = 0.5;

   R1 = ifft2(fft2(image) .* fft2(dxkernel));
   R2 = ifft2(fft2(image) .* fft2(dykernel));


   orientation = zeros(imHeight, imWidth);
   phase = zeros(imHeight, imWidth);

   orientation = (atan2(-R2, R1));

   phase = ((unwrap(atan2(sqrt(R1.^2 + R2.^2) , image))));

   amplitude = sqrt(image.^2 + R1.^2 + R2.^2);

   end
   ```
4. For each pyramid level, temporally filter the phase values of each pixel using a bandpass filter set to a frequency appropriate for the motion that you wish to magnify. Note that this removes the DC component from the phase value.
5. Calculate the amplified phase value by

   ```
   amplifiedPhase = phase + (requiredGain * filteredPhase);
   ```
6. Use the amplified phase to calculate new pixel values for each pyramid level by

   ```
   amplifiedSequence = amplitude .* cos(amplifiedPhase);
   ```
7. Collapse the pyramids to generate the new, amplified video channel.
8. Recombine your amplified channels into a new video frame.

There are some other steps in the original paper to improve noise performance, but the sequence above produces motion amplified video quite nicely.

Comment: I worked out a very similar solution (I actually stumbled upon the same document you linked). The original document states that the phase can't naively be filtered but rather the quantities "Φ*cos(Ө)" and "Φ*sin(Ө)". Did you, by any chance, try that? In my expermients it lead to a significantly increased amount of artifacts, suggesting I overlooked something.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. I can recommend their alternative pyramid structure though (rather than the Laplacian) as that does improve the results quite markedly.

Answer (score 1):

I have fully implemented the methodology of Riesz Pyramids for fast phase based video motion magnification. I felt the papers did not clearly describe the appropriate steps required to correctly filter phase. It is important to realise that mulitple mathematically correct expressions for phase and orientation may in fact not be suitable using MATLAB's acos(), asin() and atan() functions. Here is my implementation:

```
% R1, R2 are Riesz transforms of the image I and Q is the Quadrature pair

Q = sqrt((R1.^2) + (R2.^2));

phase = atan2(Q,I);
```

The phase should be wrapped to be between -pi and +pi, i.e. if phase is greater than +pi, phase = phase - 2*pi, if phase is smaller than -pi,

```
phase = phase + 2*pi.

amplitude = sqrt((I.^2) + (R1.^2) + (R2.^2));
```

**Furthermore, it is essential that the change in phase between successive frames is filtered, not the phase directly.**

```
phase_diff = phase(t+1) - phase(t);
```

This quantity "phase_diff" is temporally filtered, and amplified by multiplication with an amplification factor. The filtered, amplified, variation in phase is then used to phase shift the input.

```
magnified output = amplitude.*cos(phase_diff_filtered_amplified + original phase).
```

Answer (score 0):

whilst DrMcCleod's answer didn't directly provide a solution, it seems he was on the right track.

The complex representation of the image can be constructed from the input and the quadrature pair with

```
complexImg = complex(I, Q);
```

A phase shifted reconstruction of the image can then be generated by multiplying the complex representation with e^(-i*shift) which removes the complex part of the representation and results in the original image plus the introduced phase shift.

```
reconstructed = complexImg*exp(-sqrt(-1) * shift);
```

I'll have to experiment a little, but this seems to produce the expected results.

Thanks for the help!